# Contradictory mount errors

Tags: fsck, umount

Can anyone explain how I can unmount a disk in order to perform an fsck? I get contradictory errors:

```
fred@ARAGORN:/media/fred$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdd1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

fred@ARAGORN:/media/fred$ sudo umount /dev/sdd1
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted

fred@ARAGORN:/media/fred$ sudo fsck /dev/sdd1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdd1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

fred@ARAGORN:/media/fred$ sudo umount /dev/sdd1
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
fred@ARAGORN:/media/fred$
```

Comment: Please, provide output of `sudo mount -l` and `sudo lsof /dev/sdd1`

Comment: What does `mount | grep '^/dev/sdd1'` say? perhaps it is mounted by `fuse` or `udisks`

Comment: mount -l gives (filtering for sdd1 and related mounts):


`/dev/sdd1 on /media/fred/HDD2TB-A type ext4 (rw) [HDD2TB-A]`

`/media/fred/HDD2TB-A/home/video on /export/video type none (rw,bind)`

OK I guess this is the problem. There is a directory in the export list. Unmounting those allows fsck to work.

(Sorry can't figure out the formatting for comments. Hope you can read this ok.)